# Identify the genre of this Borderlands soundtrack?

Tags: soundtrack, identify-this-genre

I have found a track I like and would like to find out which, if any, culture normally produces music with this sound. Here is the song, [*Fighting off the Skags* by Raison Varner](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=bsBCsv4RROI).

I realize there are techno/electctronic overtones added, but I'm mostly interested in identifying the Indo-Iranian/Nepalese sounding vocals and instrument infrastructure of the track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked Raison and he said the vocals were [Tuvan Throat Singing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuvan_throat_singing):

[image]